# A forest contains 100 deer. 20 of them have a red tag and...Find the joint pmf of $X$ and $Y$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, negative-binomial

> **Exercise:** A forest contains $100$ deer. $20$ of them have a red tag and $80$ of them are untagged. A researcher samples $30$ random deer without replacement. Let $X$ be the number of tagged deer in the sample. From the sample of $30$ deer, she will keep picking deer with replacement until she picks the fourth tagged deer. Let $Y$ be the number of selections she makes until she gets her fourth tagged deer. Find the joint pmf of $X$ and $Y$.

I tried to think that: $$P_{xy}(X=x,Y=y)=P(X=x)P(Y=y\ |\ X=x)=\frac{{20\choose x}{80 \choose 30-x}}{100 \choose 30}.{{y-1}\choose 4-1}(0.2)^4(0.8)^{y-4}$$ 
$x\in \{4,5,6,....,30\}$ 
and $y\in \{4,5,6,7,.....30\}$

*Can that be a viable conclusion? If not is there a better way to tackle this kind of problems ?*

Comment: You don't seem to be dealing with the case where there are no red deer in the sample.

Comment: Interestingly, I don't know how that would work. Since if you select 0 red deer. You'll be doing the second experience an infinite time without success like a kind of loop.

Comment: I should probably state the range of x and y

Comment: It looks to me like you have a mistake. Indeed:
$$P_{xy}(X=x,Y=y)=P(X=x)P(Y=y\ |\ X=x)$$
and:
$$P(X=x)=\frac{{20\choose x}{80 \choose 30-x}}{100 \choose 30}$$
But for a given $X=x$ the probabilities in the negative binomial distribution of $Y$ will be $p=\frac{x}{30}$, so in the end it's:
$$P_{xy}(X=x,Y=y)=\frac{{20\choose x}{80 \choose 30-x}}{100 \choose 30}.{{y-1}\choose 4-1}(\frac{x}{30})^4(1-\frac{x}{30})^{y-4}$$
for $x,y \in \mathbb{N}, \quad 0 \leq x \leq 20, \quad 0 \leq y$

Comment: In the case where $X$ is zero - $P_{xy}(X=0,Y=y)=0$ for all values of $y$, I'd say that is the correct specification, but honestly I'm not sure.